# Nginx does not proxy to static files

Tags: nginx, proxy, static, gunicorn

When I run my app only with Gunicorn then I can reach app and its static (html, css, js) files. Like that: http://PUBLIC_IP:CUSTOM_PORT/static/html/blabla..

But when I run nginx which successfully listens on port 80, and I am trying to reach http://PUBLIC_IP:80/static/html/blabla..
I get 404 errors because all of these static files are not reachable for my browser.
I thought nginx would proxy everything to the internal containers but when it comes to html/css/js files, somehow it does not.

I wish to make this work from a browser perspective like this:
Browser --> http//publicIP/static/index.html ---nginx--->  (gunicorn) http://localhost:5000/static/index.html

```
My nginx.conf file:


`events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <PUBLIC-IP>;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/app.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/ec2-user/containers/frontend/flask_app/static;
        }

        }
    }`



Big thanks.
```